# Why does printf not round numbers the way I expect in my bash?

Tags: bash, printf

```
prompt> printf "%.2f\n" 3.314
3.31
prompt> printf "%.2f\n" 3.315
3.32
```

This is fine, I got what I wanted. However if I use different numbers, I get this:

```
prompt> printf "%.2f\n" 28.124
28.12
prompt> printf "%.2f\n" 28.125
28.12
```

Why was it not rounded correctly in the 2nd case? It should have been `28.13`, no?

Answer (score 4):

`printf` uses bankers' rounding (even numbers round down, odd numbers round up):

```
printf '%.2f\n' 28.125    # 28.12
printf '%.2f\n' 28.135    # 28.14
printf '%.2f\n' 28.145    # 28.14
printf '%.2f\n' 28.155    # 28.16
```

More details in [The Floating Point Guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/)

Comment: That's not the whole story though. See `bash -c 'printf "%.2f\n" 0.015'` giving 0.01 (rounded to odd) on a GNU/Linux amd64 system for instance. `bash -c 'printf "%s %.2f %.1000g\n" "$@"' bash .{0..9}{0..9}5{,,}` helps to see what's going on.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas now that's interesting... I get different results for the number set in my answer using `%.2f` from `bash` and `dash`

Comment: yes, bash uses long doubles and dash/zsh use doubles. See my answer in the linked Q&A for more details. (I've removed the original duplicate BTW as it was potentially misleading as it was about `interger.5` numbers which can all be represented in binary (at least for the smaller ones)).

Comment: Thanks. "_I've removed the original duplicate_" - please feel free (on my score, at least) to undup this question if relevant